# Read a file line by line with condition in shell script

Tags: bash

i have a file errorgot.log

```
1 23 23
2 22 42
3 12 2
4 5 26
5 14 45
```

i want to sum all the third number in a line with a shell script.
for the example, 23 + 42 + 2 + 26 + 45 = 138

thanks bfore

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk '{sum += $3}END{print sum}' errorgot.log
```

How does it work?

- `awk` reading file line by line, split each line by a separator (white space by default) and assign to numbered variables (`$1` for the first column, `$2` for the second and so on)
- after that `awk` executing the code between braces (`{sum += $3}`). In our case, we're accumulating sum in the variable `sum`
- after processing a file, `awk` executes code from `END` section where we're printing `sum` variable